# Find the inductive definition of {$a^m b^n | m, n \in N$ where m > 0 and n >0}

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Having some trouble find the inductive definition of {$a^m b^n | m, n \in N$ where m > 0 and n >0} , its more complex then I'm use to dealing with. Can someone explain please , thank you!

Comment: you can apply currying to work with one variable at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suitable inductive definition over that domain would be
$$
a^1 b^1 \equiv ab\\
\mbox{if } n > 1 \ a^1 b^n \equiv (a^1b^{n-1})b \\
\mbox{if } m > 1 \mbox{ then } a^mb^n \equiv a(a^{m-1}b^n) \\
$$